# TCP socket + socket.io bidirectional (JSON-)RPC: dnode?

Tags: node.js, rpc, socket.io, json-rpc, dnode

I'm looking for a way to implement a bidirectional RPC in **node.js** (means that both client and server provide remote-callable procedures, preferable like json-rpc). It should be usable on top of socket.io and TCP/IP sockets for clients. I was about to use **nowjs** for websockets and provide a seperate API for "normal" sockets.

Now I just found **[dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode)** which claims to work with both. "It works over network sockets and even in the browser with socket.io."

I need to pass **JSON objects** (containing strings) to each other side. The clients will be written in **JavaScript** (Browser), JavaScript (Appcelerator Titanium), **C#** and maybe **Java** (Android), but there's only an implementation for Java. I read the [protocol](https://github.com/substack/dnode-protocol) and I think it's not that easy to implement.

Also there is a method name exchange after connection is established which would be quite a overhead in my application, I don't need it as I know what I implemented on the other side (it's not a public api).

**Someone has experience with it or know alternatives?** I'm not sure if it's the right thing for my purpose, I need to implement **CRUD** and **PUB/SUB**.

Comment: Dnode and nowjs both do method names exchange. What is your reason for not just using socket.io?

Comment: I need to answer the request which isn't that nice in socket.io (emit a new event). In nowjs you have a nice callback function. NowJS does? Didn't know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **socket.io** , it has support for **rooms** which can be stored **memory** or a **Redis Pub/Sub** implementation.
You can also **namespace** your sockets and provide **CRUD** through events.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

var someResource = io
  .of('/someResource')
  .on('create', function (socket) {
    createSomeResource()
  })
  .on('read', function(socket) {
    readSomeResource(id, function(){
      io.sockets.in('roomBasedOnSessionId').emit('data', {my:'json'})
    })
  })
```

Here is a **great** walkthrough of some of the topics you'll need, including references to sockets and session sharing.
http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Comment: Yes I'm using socket.io now. I found out that socket.io does support callbacks/direct answers. It's hidden in "how to use".